# How to get the autocorrelation of this finite discrete function?

Tags: autocorrelation

This is the function:

$$
x(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{-N  $\leq$ n $\leq$ N ;}\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

And I tried to solve it, using sigma notation or summation:

\begin{equation}
\ r_{xx}(l) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n)x(n-l) \end{equation}

I get 2N-1 but that is wrong. Because when I do the autocorrelation in MATLAB I get something like:
For exmple if N = 2, the discrete function rxx(l) would be like:[image]

Which is something like rxx(l) = 2N-1+|l|
But I don't know how to get there... Can you help me?

Comment: In your definition $\displaystyle r_{xx}(l) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n)x(n-l), $ for $l = 3$ and with $N=5$, say, can you _list_ all the _nonzero terms_ in that sum $r_{xx}(3)$? If you think this is too much work, how about just the value of $x(6)x(6-3)$ and $x(5)x(5-3)$?

Answer (score 3):

Calculating the autocorrelation of this function is relatively easy. You just need to follow the formula you have written:

\begin{equation}
\ r_{xx}(l) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n)x(n-l) \end{equation}

It gets much easier because your function is $\neq0$ for only a few values ($2N+1$ exactly).

Because of this the previous sum can be replaced with this much simpler one:

\begin{equation}
\ r_{xx}(l) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-N}^{N} x(n-l) \end{equation}

Which is basically just counting how many times $x(n-l)$ is not zero on that finite interval. Because of this it appears easily that

\begin{equation}
r_{xx}(l)=max(2N-1-|l|,0)  \end{equation}

You almost had it in your question but the sign was wrong.